# Simple SwiftUI Arc endAngle animation not working, only jump from one state to another

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a simple animation of the appearance of the arc.
This is very simple, and I don't have any idea why is not working. 
I make this struct

```
struct Arc: Shape {
    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    var endAngle: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(endAngle), clockwise: false)

        return path
    }
}
```

And after that load it like this

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var endAngle: Double = 180

    var body: some View {
            Arc(center: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250), radius: 100, endAngle: self.endAngle)
                .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 5)
                .onAppear() {
                    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 20)) {
                        self.endAngle = 0
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

But is not animate, only jump from 180 to 0.
I try OnTapGesture too, but also dosn't work. 
I don't now, why this dosn't work

My ContentView is simple

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      TestView()
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add animatable data to your `Arc`, to indicate which parameter should be animated, as below

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct Arc: Shape {
    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    var endAngle: Double

    var animatableData: CGFloat {     // << here !!
        get { CGFloat(endAngle) }
        set { endAngle = Double(newValue) }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(endAngle), clockwise: false)

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I rename endAngle to animatableData and works too :)