# Unable to animate SwiftUI Shape with included animatable data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to animate an arc to the left and right form its center (270 deg in Shape terms). This requires animatable data, which I've added, but the arc still doesn't seem to animate.

The view using the Arc is below. I've commented my intentions with the properties.

```
struct AverageGauge: View {
    
    @State var endAngle: Angle = Angle(degrees: 271.0)
    
    var clockwise: Bool {
        get { endAngle.degrees > 270 ? false : true }
    }
    

    
    var body: some View {
        Arc(startAngle: .degrees(270), endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: clockwise)
            .stroke(.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
           // Tap gesture as stand in for changing data
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 10.0)) {
                    endAngle = Angle(degrees: Double.random(in: 180...360))
                }
            }
    }
}

struct Arc: Shape {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var clockwise: Bool
    
    // Animatable endAngle
    var endAngleAnimatable: Angle {
        get { endAngle }
        set { endAngle = newValue }
    }
    
    // Animatable clockwise bool 
    var clockwiseAnimatable: Bool {
        get { clockwise }
        set { clockwise = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.width / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngleAnimatable, clockwise: clockwiseAnimatable)

        return path
    }
}
```

When I set the `clockwise` in the Arc to a constant, it still doesn't animate, so I suppose the `Bool` isn't what's causing the problem.

Here's a gif of the arc being instantly redrawn rather than animated:
[image: arc]

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What is the `Arc` shape you are using? Custom shapes are not animatable simply because they are `Shapes`.

Comment: Arc added along with an animation.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61221522/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using `Double` for `endAngle` rather than `Angle`. The `Double` is then converted to an `Angle` using `.degrees(Double)` in the arc. I guess creating `Angle`s isn't animatable.

Comment: Your animatable data must conform to `VectorMath` to work. Essentially, when you write the `Shape`, you must teach it how to animate.

Comment: Ok..conformed `Angle` to `VectorArithmetic` and it works without having to use `Double`. Added answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Yrb's suggestion above, I conformed `Angle` to `VectorArithmetic` and the animation works without having to change `endAngle` do a `Double`:

```
extension Angle: VectorArithmetic {
    
    public static var zero = Angle(degrees: 0.0)
    
    public static func + (lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
        Angle(degrees: lhs.degrees + rhs.degrees)
    }
    
    public static func - (lhs: Angle, rhs: Angle) -> Angle {
        Angle(degrees: lhs.degrees - rhs.degrees)
    }
    
    public static func += (lhs: inout Angle, rhs: Angle) {
        lhs = Angle(degrees: lhs.degrees + rhs.degrees)
    }
    
    public static func -= (lhs: inout Angle, rhs: Angle) {
        lhs = Angle(degrees: lhs.degrees - rhs.degrees)
    }
    
    public mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        self.degrees = self.degrees * rhs
    }
    
    public var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        get { 0.0 }
    }
}
```

`magnitudeSquared` isn't properly implemented. Just a filler stub.